# What is the difference between 'x' and "x"?

Tags: c++, string, char, difference

What is the difference between `'x'` and `"x"`?

Does `'x'` mean it is a `char` value and `"x"` mean it is a string value?

very sorry for the similarity to the other qn as I don't really get the explanation over there as it is too complicated.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely the difference.

Comment: @BrianBi as long as "string" means "string literal".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The literal `'x'` is a `char`. The literal `"x"` is a *string literal* of type `const char[2]`, a null-terminated char array holding values `x` and `\0`.

Comment: I'm being picky, but it should be "null-terminated" not "null terminated." :P

Comment: @TimothyShields And I agree. Edited.

Comment: `"x"` is not like any `const char[2]` though, it is literal which allows it to initialize arrays with `=`.

Answer (score 0):

your assumption is correct,

```
"x" is a string
'x' is a char
```

Comment: I would be careful calling it a string in C++. It is a CString (null terminated array of characters) not an std::string. The fact you can assign one to the other doesn't mean they are the same.

Comment: @harmic Even [CString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) is confusing, because there is a class out there with that name.

Comment: Basically, a char value is just a char value. A string is simply an array of chars, ended with a null terminator. There are different implementations of this idea, I.E. CString and std::string, but the basic idea is the same

Comment: @juanchopanza yeah I forgot that one. Ok, "C style string".

Comment: "There are different implementations of this idea". No, `"x"` is neither an `std::string` or a CString`. It is a string literal, and it can only be of one type.

Comment: Well yea it can only have one type, I'm just saying that the way the chars are stored are essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

'x' means a char with value 'x'.

"x" means a c-type const char array with value {'x', 0}

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, "x" is of type `const char[]` which is an array and it is null-terminated (0x00). Whilst 'x' is of type `char`.
The word 'string' is a little bit ambiguous, because it can mean two things -

- A string of characters (`const char[]`)
- The datatype `std::string`. C++ has support in the standard library for the String datatype, which can be assigned a `const char[]`.

Just to clarify:

> "I am"

Is actually this:

> {'I', ' ', 'a', 'm', '\0'}